# How do I overlay a <textarea> on top of an <iframe>?

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I want to be able to use a full screen textarea on top of a video that is playing. I thought position: fixed; top: 0; might work but it did not.

HTML

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HIDDEN?rel=0?version=3&autoplay=1&controls=0&&showinfo=0&loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<textarea></textarea>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

textarea {
  position: fixed;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parent element with `position: relative` then use `position: absolute` on the `textarea` to put it where you want.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

textarea {
  position: absolute;
  resize: none;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HIDDEN?rel=0?version=3&autoplay=1&controls=0&&showinfo=0&loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
```